# The time-complexity of using object as a dictionary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hash, hashmap, time-complexity

I am considering using JavaScript object as a dictionary.

```
    var dict = {}
    dict['a'] = 1;
    dict['b'] = 2;

    var my_first = dict['a'];
```

I am not clear about the time-complexity of such implementation. Is it like hashing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaScript objects are often *called* "hashes" (mostly by recovering Perl addicts) or "hash tables" (unrepentant Java people).  The typical look-up is somewhere between O(1) and O(log n).

Comment: 'associative arrays', as well.

Comment: Could you provide a source?